# Maven failure on spring boot test (junit 5)

Tags: java, maven, testing, spring-boot, junit5

Is it possible to run spring boot tests with junit 5 using maven?
I'm using spring boot 2.0.0.M3, junit 5.0.0-M6, maven 3.5.0. Other junit5 tests (without spring context) works.

There is simple controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

and test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(HomeController.class)
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
class HomeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void shouldReturnHomeTemplate() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string(startsWith("<!DOCTYPE html>")));
    }
}
```

Everything works when I run it using intellij, but maven build ends with failure:

> [WARNING] Corrupted stdin stream in forked JVM 1. See the dump file
>          somePath/target/surefire-reports/2017-07-28T13-50-15_071-jvmRun1.dumpstream

--debug flag shows:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Inside `2017-07-28T13-50-15_071-jvmRun1.dumpstream` I can find ~100 same exceptions (one per spring log):

> Corrupted stdin stream in forked JVM 1. Stream '
>           13:50:15.914 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - 
>               Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class 
>           [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]'.
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Stream stdin corrupted. 
>           Expected comma after third character in command '
>               13:50:15.914 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - 
>                   Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class 
>                    [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]'.
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient$OperationalData.(ForkClient.java:469)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.processLine(ForkClient.java:191)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ForkClient.consumeLine(ForkClient.java:158)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.output.ThreadedStreamConsumer$Pumper.run(ThreadedStreamConsumer.java:87)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Maven surefire plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-M6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Which version maven-surefire-plugin do you use? Which java version do you use? How many memory have you defined for the JVM ?

Comment: Maven surefire plugin config added. I'm using java 8 (it's required for spring boot 2). Memory settings for maven/jvm are default. Just using: `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Is there really a need to run with JUnit 5 ? Can you show the full pom file?  You say memory is default ? But what are the defaults?

Comment: Did you define a different memory configuration for your test in IntelliJ?

Comment: In IntellijJ Build... -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing -> VM options for importer: -Xmx768m
I tried setting surefire-plugin config:
`<configuration>
  <argLine>-Xmx1024m -Xmx1024m</argLine>
</configuration>`
But nothing changed

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ bundles JUnit5 so IntelliJ and Maven are probably using different versions.

[See the JUnit5 docs about IntelliJ](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide-intellij-idea)

Depending on which version of IntelliJ you are running, it is probably executing an earlier `JUnit5` milestone release than what maven is using.

If you're on `2017.2`, you could try switching your `JUnit5` dependency in your `pom.xml` back to `M4` and see if that solves the incompatibility.

Also try specifying the `junit-jupiter-engine:5.0.0-M4` in the plugin dependency in your `pom.xml` as well as `junit-platform-surefire-plugin`.

I am using `5.0.0-M5` successfully this way.

**[UPDATE 2017-08-10]:** regarding your comments, I am using spring boot `1.5.4.RELEASE` so I can't do a like-for-like comparison.

You don't say what version of IntelliJ you are using - assuming the tests are still working under IntelliJ, that version configuration is your target, presumably. Look in the maven projects view or debug the test output to get the classpath and see what versions are in use.

Spring is probably managing a lot of the versions for you. Are you using the spring-boot parent pom, or depending on the `spring-boot-starter` dependencies?

To find out what is going on and which spring dependency is pulling in which `JUnit5` dependency that is breaking, run

`mvn dependency:tree`

and go through the list of dependencies and versions to see exactly what you have under maven.

You may find the versions you think you have specified are being overridden, and  you have to put exclusions in the pom to stop that.

**[UPDATE 2]:** just a quick change - try putting the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency in your `maven-surefire-plugin` dependency block next to `junit-platform-surefire-provider`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider
                    </artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Note I'm also not yet on version `2.20` (and I'm still on `5.0.0-M5`) - sorry but I don't have time to try it this week either.

You could also see if setting the `maven-surefire-plugin` config `forkCount=0` to see if that gives you a better exception message.

You could strip down your project to the bare minimum and open Jira issues with [Maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/SUREFIRE) and [Spring testing](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15274?jql=project%20%3D%20SPR%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Test%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC). I changed the tags on your question to incluide `spring-boot` so one of their guys might take notice. Or might not, depending on your luck - I find they are more likely to react if you tweet your stackoverflow url to @springboot.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I tried many combinations with dependencies, versions and I can't make it working (versions `M4`, `M5`, or `RC2`). Can you provide all your dependencies with versions connected with junit? Are you using `@WebMvcTest` or `@SpringBootTest` with `spring-boot:2.0.0.M3`?

Comment: update:
I'm using newest intellij `2017.2.1` and `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.M3`
Using `mvn dependency:tree` or showing dependency diagram I can see correct versions of artifacts which I set (all junit with same milestone).
I think it's problem with `maven-surefire-plugin`. It can't handle newest `junit5` with `spring boot 2`.

Comment: Thank you very much, there must be bug in `maven-surefire-plugin:2.20`. I changed it to `2.19.1` and everything works like a charm :) - with any `junit5` version and `spring-boot:2.0.0.M3`

Comment: created jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1406

Comment: having same issue with DropWizard. To make it work, had to downgrade from 2.20 to 2.19.1

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the interaction between the `maven-surefire-plugin` an JUnit5's `junit-vintage-engine`, that writes to System.out before Surefire is able to handle this.

It was fixed in `maven-surefire-plugin` version 2.22.2: https://blogs.apache.org/maven/entry/apache-maven-surefire-plugin-version2